# How to customize the parts titles in the TOC?

Tags: titles, parts

I'd like to customize the parts titles in order to have centered titles in the TOC. How could I do that?

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don’t want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A title}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
    
\frontmatter
\part{Why is Latex so complicated?}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
    
\mainmatter
\part{How to customize a part section?}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
% tocpartprob.tex SE 649116

\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%%%% center part titles
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hfil\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hfil}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don’t want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A title}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
    
\frontmatter
\part{Why is Latex so complicated?}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
    
\mainmatter
\part{How to customize a part section?}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Thank you for the MWE, which I have altered slightly.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I forgot to mention that I need to modify also the TOC's numbering. Ideally, it should be like this: First part (not a number) and just below the title.

Comment: @domi It seems that the answer solves your problem as initially stated, so please acknowledge the answer. Ask another question related to the numbering with an appropriate MWE showing what you have tried and what the problem is.