# How to create a part title with subtitle?

Tags: titles, tocloft, parts

I'd like to customize my TOC in order to get the following layout (see picture below).

[image]

As you can see, there is three parts in this title part: a number with letters ("First part"), a title ("Why is Latex so complicated?") and a subtitle ("Answers and questions"). How could I modify the [following MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649116/how-to-customize-the-parts-titles-in-the-toc/649127?noredirect=1#comment1618135_649127) in order to get this result?

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%%%% center part titles
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hfil\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hfil}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don’t want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A title}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
    
\frontmatter
\part{Why is Latex so complicated?}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
    
\mainmatter
\part{How to customize a part section?}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully customize the `toc` behaviors, you probably need to redefine the `\l@part` and `\@part` command. To understand how these internal commands defined, you need take a look the `book.cls` file. I add a new counter to represent the order of the part in "First, Second, Third...etc". I only define the case up to 10 parts. If you need more than 10, you need extend the definition in command `\partorder`. You didn't mention if you want the page number to be follow after the part entry in toc. I will assume you do. Also right now the part title in document are still in the original form (e.g. Part I title...). I am not sure if you want those are also in the form "First Part title...", so I didn't change it. I load the `hyperref` package because you have `hidelinks` option in your `\documentclass`. If you don't load `hyperref` package, this option is useless. And because you wanna manually line break in the part title, you could do that by putting `\\` in the title. However if `hyperref` loaded, the `\\` are not allowed in the PDF bookmarks. You need use `\texorpdfstring{}{}` to tell latex how this title will be typed in the PDF bookmarks.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\hfill\parbox{0.6\linewidth}{\centering\large \bfseries #1}\hfill
       \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                          \kern-\p@\kern\p@}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\newcounter{partorder}
\newcommand{\partorder}{%
\ifcase\value{partorder}\or First\or Second\or Third\or Fourth\or Fifth\or Sixth\or Seventh\or Eighth\or Ninth\or Tenth\else ??(out range)\fi%
} % If you have more than 10 parts, you need extend this define

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}\stepcounter{partorder}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\partorder\space\partname\\#1}{\partorder\space\partname\ --\ #1}}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don’t want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A title}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
    
\frontmatter
\part{\texorpdfstring{Why is Latex so complicated?\\Answer and questions}{Why is Latex so complicated?\ --\ Answer and questions}}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
    
\mainmatter
\part{How to customize a part section?}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum

\setcounter{part}{10}
\setcounter{partorder}{10}
\part{\texorpdfstring{How about more than 10 parts?\\You need define it in \textbackslash partorder command}{How about more than 10 parts?\ -- \ You need define it in \textbackslash partorder command}}
\chapter{Another chapter}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It works. Thanks for your advices!

Comment: Maybe am I wrong, but it seems that there is an extra space between the words "First" and "part".

Comment: @domi No, I didn't see it.